# interpretation of interaction effect in linear regression - given one log variable

Tags: r, interaction

Hopefully someone can help me with the following. My question is how to intrepret the interaction effect of the following interaction log(X3):X2 = (B4)0.004. Is it possible to use log-lin or log-log interpretation, or do I have to use some other measure for interpretation?

regression used: log(DV) ~ log(X1) + (X2 *log(X3))

I tried to use untransformed variables as explanatory variables, but this model delivers only half the adjusted r-square of the above model. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are both X2 and X3 continuous?  (I guess X3 is, otherwise it makes little sense to take a log)

Comment: It will help if you write parameters on your regression equation.

Answer (score 0):

Say $\beta_2$ is associated with $x_2$, $\beta_3$ with $\log x_3$ and $\beta_4$ with the interaction effect.
The basic interpretation is independent of log-s: one unit larger $x_2 \cdot \log x_3$ is associated with $\beta_4$-unit larger $\log DV$.

- Now one unit larger $x_2$ is associated with $\beta_2 + \beta_4\log x_3$ units larger log outcome, or $\exp(\beta_2 + \beta_4\log x_3)$ times larger outcome.
  If $\beta_2 + \beta_4 \log x_3$ is small, this is roughly equal by being larger by $100\times(\beta_2 + \beta_4\log x_3)$ percent.
  So $\beta_4\log x_3$ describes the "total effect" of $x_2$.
- In an analogous fashion, for one unit larger $\log x_3$ your log outcome is larger by $\beta_3 + \beta_4 x_2$ units, and the outcome by exp this much times.

Maybe the one unit larger $\log x_3$... is not a good way to think about the problem, so you may think in terms of *one 1% larger $x_3$* instead.  If so, then $\log x_3$ is larger by $\log 1.01 \approx 0.01$ and we can rephrase the second point as:

- For those cases where $x_3$ is larger by 1%, the outcome is larger by $100\times(\beta_3 + \beta_4 x_2)$ percent.

This is perhaps my favorite interpretation: $\beta_4 x_2$ shows the additional effect of $x_3$ (in terms of percentages).  Or alternatively, you can say $\beta_4\log x_3$ shows the additional effect of $x_2$.

Would be good to know more about the problem and what do you consider a good interpretation.

Note that you should avoid causality when interpreting these results, logs or no logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. My aim is to quantify the total effect on the dependent variable by X2 & X3, including the interaction effect. Such that I can make sense of the numbers in a analogous manner. I will elaborate a bit more on the different variables, which would hopefully help your understanding of my question better.
All variables are continuous. The log used is the natural logarithm. The formula is as follow in terms of parameters:

---

> ln(Volume FTSC) = ln(Subject likes) + (subject polarity * ln(subject retweets))

This results in three effects(B1,B2,B3) of each independent variable and one interaction effect(B4). Let's assume the model is significant and so are the following effects:

1. B1 = -0.001      (ln likes)
2. B2 =  0.003      (!not ln transformed!)
3. B3 =  0.001      (ln retweets)
4. B4 =  0.002      (interaction x2*ln(x3))

I believe B1,B2,B3 individually can be interpreted following the log - log principal in which one percent increase in X1,X2,X3 results in Y of b%.

---

So, if I understand Ott correctly, where x3 is 1% larger the total effect on Volume(Y) is larger by **100 * (0.001 + 0.002*x2) = (0,1 + 0,2*x2)%.** Can simply assume x1 stays constant at 1?

> So that you can interpet the results as where x3 is 1% larger (**given x2 = 1**)  results in **0,3%** increase in Y(Volume).

Secondly, if I am correct, you can't use the 1% analog for the b2 total effect since it's not ln transformed. Therefore, the way I interpret Ott's explanation you can say: one unit more of x2 has a **|100 * ( 0.003 + 0.002* log x3)% = (0.3 +0.2 * ln x3)%|** times larger outcome of Y.

> So, one unit more of X2 would result in aprroximately **1.22%** increase of Y, when inserting **100(retweets)** in the formula above.

Hopefully I interpreted properly and please let me know what you think of these interpretations. I will be grateful for any feedback!